# How to create multiple chart using single query result data

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a query which returning me 40 row each row has number_of_bugs_closed and  closed_date. The closed_date value rage
from May and Jun month.

Now I have to create 3 report chart in JasperReports

1. Graph to show number of closed bugs every day.
2. Graph to show number of closed bugs every week.
3. Graph to show number of closed bugs every month.

Can we create these 3 chart using single query result data, or we have create 3 different queries?

Is it possible to do in jasper by using some script or other way?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might use some kind of date check in your query.
Something like

> where date between may and jun

Instead create two parameters, say **`$P{TimeCheck}`** and **`$P{TimeRange}`**.

In which, **$P{TimeCheck}** parameter will be used in the ***query for time comparison*** and parameter **$P{TimeRange}** will be used to **derive the value of parameter $P{TimeCheck}**. Pass different **$P{TimeRange}** value for different charts **while mapping the parameters**, say for example, for **month** chart ***$P{TimeRange}='month'***, for **week** chart, ***$P{TimeRange}='week'*** and for **everyday** chart, ***$P{TimeRange}='all'***.

Parameter **$P{TimeCheck}** should has the following expression ***`"$P{TimeRange} == 'week' ? 'date in (startdate or enddate of everyweek)' : $P{TimeRange} == 'month' ? 'date in (startdate or enddate of every month)' : 'date between may and jun'"`***

Now use this parameter in the where condition as **`where $P!{TimeCheck}`**

**Note: Donot use the main query. Try to create a dataset and use the query.**

I hope this should solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

It will better use different data set for for each chart. Or You can use same data set but this is going to be so difficult to develop. You can try this by using following steps:

you need to add column (say week number)in your sql query and calculate the week number for dates to this column. like select week(yourdate) give you the week number.

Now you have three columns in your dataset with week number.

If you use week_number as category in your Jasper Charts it will give you the charts but the value for that is not matching.

reason: jasper add value for column number_of_bugs_closed but also devides it by week_number. 
example: you have two rows for for first week. then it will calculate it and divide it by two.

Which means you need another column(say week_number_of_bugs_closed) that is multiple of number of week_number and number_of_bugs_closed.

To calculate the number of week_number , you need to make a join which will give you the total number of day in that particular week.

You can refer below query which shows structure of query.

```
select a.*,b.week_count, week_number_of_bugs_closed * b.week_count as week_value from
(select xyz.number_of_bugs_closed , xyz.closed_date ,week(closed_date)         as week_number from xyz) a
join 
(select week(closed_date) week_number, count(*) as week_count from xyz group by week(closed_date) ) b  on 
     a.week_number = b.week_number
```

Now you can use the category week_number and its value as week_value to weekly chart.

You can use the similar approach for monthly chart.

I hope , I am able to explain the concepts.